# Ошибки при компиляции qt

Tags: c++, qt

Установил mingw. Вот версия компилятора:
6.3.0.
Версия установленного qt 4.8.4.
Для компиляции проекта использую следующие команды:

```
qmake -project
qmake
make
```

Выдаёт следующее:

```
/h/GUI/"C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f Makefile.Debug
/bin/sh: /h/GUI/C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe: No such file or directory
make.exe": *** [debug] Error 127
```

Если пишу mingw32-make выдаёт это:

```
C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'H:/GUI'
Makefile.Debug:62: *** missing separator.  Stop.
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'H:/GUI'
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'debug' failed
mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2
```

Переменная PATH содержит следующее:

```
C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Qt\4.8.4\bin;C:\PROGRA~2\Borland\CBUILD~1\Bin;C:\PROGRA~2\Borland\CBUILD~1\Projects\Bpl;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему возникает данная ситуация ? Я пробовал делал всё тоже самое на виртуальной машине, установил win 7 и поставил все нужные мне файлы, но ошибка сохраняется. Что я делаю неправильно ?

Comment: Попробуйте поставить MSYS2 вместо обычного MSYS.

Comment: а вы какую версию Qt ставили, случайно не для Visual Studio? непонятно почему qmake сделал несъедобный Makefile.Debug

Comment: @Pavel Gridin Версия qt 4.8.4. Я делаю всё через блокнот и консоль.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Дело в том, что обычно всё работает из коробки. Я имею в виду, что после установки mingw и qt всё компилировалось замечательно, сейчас какие то проблемы.

Comment: @New_Geek, Qt для windows, не зависимо от версии, для разных компиляторов собирается по разному и вы должны установить Qt для mingw, чтобы всё правильно работало. Основная разница в том, как qmake будет преобразовывать qt-проекты. https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.4/

Comment: @Pavel Gridin Спасибо вам большое. Действительно была скачана не та версия. Я уже голову сломал. Огромное вам спасибо :)

Comment: @PavelGridin mingw32-make работает, exe файл создаётся, но открыть его невозможно. Команда make выдаёт прежнюю ошибку, что файл не найден.

Comment: @Pavel Gridin и на win 7 не работает. Windows не блокирует его. Что то видимо не настроено или установлено неправильно

Comment: @New_Geek, можно попробовать Qt Creator, он обычно ругается во время настройки Tolls/Options/Kits если видит нестыковки версий Qt, make, компилятора, отладчика ...